# Is allocating in an oft called function inefficient on the CLR/Mono?

Tags: mobile, memory-management, mono, clr, monogame

I'm playing with MonoGame right now, and I was investigating the SpriteBatch.Draw() method.

Inside of the method, which can be called tens of thousands of times per second, I see the following:

```
public void Draw (Texture2D texture,
        Rectangle destinationRectangle,
        Rectangle? sourceRectangle,
        Color color,
        float rotation,
        Vector2 origin,
        SpriteEffects effect,
        float depth)
    {
        CheckValid(texture);

        DrawInternal(texture,
              new Vector4(destinationRectangle.X, //<-------------- Oh Noes! :O
                          destinationRectangle.Y,
                          destinationRectangle.Width,
                          destinationRectangle.Height),
              sourceRectangle,
              color,
              rotation,
              new Vector2(origin.X * ((float)destinationRectangle.Width (float)texture.Width), <-- Oh Noes!
                          origin.Y * ((float)destinationRectangle.Height / (float)texture.Height)),
              effect,
              depth);
    }
```

It would seem that thousands of new vectors are being allocated every 60th of a second or so.

MonoGame is a platform which is meant for (among other things) mobile development. I did some mobile development which ran on Dalvik, and allocating in this manner was never a good idea. On slow mobile processors the build up of objects in need of collection would eventually cause GC to run and cause a noticeable dip in performance (up to 200 milliseconds on some devices). Which leads me to my question:

Is there something about the way the CLR/Mono GC runs, or some other factor, that would prevent this performance hit from occurring, or is MonoGame doing something it shouldn't in one of its most called functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`Vector4` type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.vector4.aspx) is not a class, it's a structure. Creating a new instance of it doesn't create an object on the heap, it creates a structure value. In this case the value is pushed onto the stack for the method call, so it's basically the same work as pushing the members as separate parameters.

Comment: `struct` may be allocated on the stack or the heap. This depends on the scope of the object. If you create a closure referencing a `struct`, for example, the `struct` gets lifted from the stack to prolong it's lifetime. Eric Lippert puts it quite nicely in his [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail.aspx). [This one too](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/09/30/the-truth-about-value-types.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Guffa/Mike! I'm going to read those articles right now. I've been using Java for so long I'd completely forgotten about Structs! I'm glad to know I can create and use such objects on the fly without worrying about GC, it will lead to cleaner and less confusing code on this platform compared to the one I was previously working with.

Comment: @MikeBantegui: Yes, but the struct is still not allocated on the heap by itself, it's the closure that is allocated on the heap.